# How to send notification from iOS App to Apple Carplay

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, sirikit, carplay

I want when my iOS App receives Notification, it's will display on Carplay too. But [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/carplay/overview/messaging-and-voip-apps/) about this topic so simple, have no idea how to implement

Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you have a CarPlay messaging entitlement for your app from Apple?  If so, you need to create a notification category with the allow in CarPlay option and assign that category to the notifications that you want to show

Comment: I tried but not thing happen when I tested on simulator. Anyway, I have send you a message in Skype, can you take a look ?

Comment: I think notifications not work in Simulator

Comment: @Paulw11 so, to enable push notification I should have CarPlay messaging entitlement?